# Display categories thumbnails Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using Category Thumbnails 1.0.5 Plugin and I want to display all categories and their thumbnails in a template page that i created.
I read the documentation and saw how to display the thumbnail of a specific category, but i can't display all categories and all thumbnails with a loop.

I'm trying to get the name of each category with this code

```
$args = array('type' => 'post');
$categories = get_categories($args);
foreach($categories as $cat) {
    the_category_thumbnail($cat->cat_ID);
    $cat->name;
}
```

But it is not working for me.

Any clue about it?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Get all categories, then in loop display each category with its thumbnail.
For more info go to wordpress.com and search got  get_categories
And php.net  for `for loop`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it might be a bit of a long winded way but it seems to work. This code should output your category image followed by the name.

```
$args = array('type' => 'post');
$categories = get_categories( $args );
foreach ($categories as $cat) {
      $size = 'full'; //can also be value: 'thumbnail'
      $thumbnail_id = get_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
      $image = wp_get_attachment_image( $thumbnail_id, $size );
      echo '<br />' .$image;
      echo '<br />' . $cat->name;
}
```

[See here for details on the function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/)